# Vertical Scrollbar in tkinter output window (using grid)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to display the data in my database using a tkinter window, but since my DB has more than 400 tuples, it doesn't display on screen, as shown in the [output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwlAt.png).

**How should I add a scrollbar to the window?**

I've seen a few examples of a Canvas and Frame being used, but I'm unfamiliar with them as this is my first tk program.
My code is as follows:

```
def displayPlayer(data):

            Label1 = Label(master, text="First Name", width=20)
            Label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
            Label2 = Label(master, text="Last Name", width=20)
            Label2.grid(row=0, column=1)
            Label3 = Label(master, text="Nationality", width=20)
            Label3.grid(row=0, column=2)
            Label4 = Label(master, text="Club", width=20)
            Label4.grid(row=0, column=3)
            Label5 = Label(master, text="Age", width=10)
            Label5.grid(row=0, column=4)
            Label6 = Label(master, text="Years at Club", width=10)
            Label6.grid(row=0, column=5)
            Label7 = Label(master, text="Agent", width=20)
            Label7.grid(row=0, column=6)
            Label8 = Label(master, text="Rating", width=10)
            Label8.grid(row=0, column=7)
            Label9 = Label(master, text="Position", width=10)
            Label9.grid(row=0, column=8)


            for index, dat in enumerate(data):
                    Label(master, text=dat[0]).grid(row=index+1, column=0)
                    Label(master, text=dat[1]).grid(row=index+1, column=1)
                    Label(master, text=dat[2]).grid(row=index+1, column=2)
                    Label(master, text=dat[3]).grid(row=index+1, column=3)
                    Label(master, text=dat[4]).grid(row=index+1, column=4)
                    Label(master, text=dat[5]).grid(row=index+1, column=5)
                    Label(master, text=dat[6]).grid(row=index+1, column=6)
                    Label(master, text=dat[7]).grid(row=index+1, column=7)
                    Label(master, text=dat[8]).grid(row=index+1, column=8)




        def allPlayer():
            cursor.execute("SELECT * from Players")
            data=cursor.fetchall()
            displayPlayer(data)
```

Comment: yiu have to learn how to use canvas to scroll frame - my simple example with class [ScrolledFrame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas/scrolled-frame.py) or you can use [Treeview](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) (instead of `Labels`) and add `Scrollbar`.

Comment: BTW: you can use `enumerate(data, 1):` and then you can use `index` instead of `index+1`

Comment: BTW: instead of all labels in `for index, dat ` you could use one line `for col in range(9): Label(master, text=dat[col]).grid(row=index+1, column=col)`

Comment: I tried to use Treeview to display the data, but I am not familiar with it, so all the tuples appears horizontally (all rows continuously in one row & repeated for all rows n times). Any help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Frame` with `Canvas` to scroll it.

I have simple class `ScrolledFrame` which I can use many times in code. I other questions on SO you could find other `ScrolledFrame` with more options and you don't have to create own one.

I changed your `displayPlayer` to make it shorter and to use different `master`.

I used `random` and `string` to generate some random data to display in table.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---

class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, vertical=True, horizontal=False):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed

        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news") # changed

        self._vertical_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self._canvas.yview)
        if vertical:
            self._vertical_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._vertical_bar.set)

        self._horizontal_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self._canvas.xview)
        if horizontal:
            self._horizontal_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we")
        self._canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._horizontal_bar.set)

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self._canvas)
        self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)

    def resize(self, event=None): 
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox("all"))

# --- functions ---

def display_players(master, data):

    headers = [
       ("First Name", 20),
       ("Last Name", 20),
       ("Nationality", 20),
       ("Club", 20),
       ("Age", 10),
       ("Years at Club", 10),
       ("Agent", 20),
       ("Rating", 10),
       ("Position", 10),
    ]

    # create row with headers
    for col, (header, size) in enumerate(headers):
        l = tk.Label(master, text=header, width=size)
        l.grid(row=0, column=col)

    # create rows with players
    for row, player in enumerate(data, 1):
        for col in range(9):
            l = tk.Label(master, text=player[col])
            l.grid(row=row, column=col)

# --- main ---

# - create random data for test -

import random
import string

data = []
for rows in range(20):
    row = []
    for cols in range(9):
        row.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
    data.append(row)

# - start -

root = tk.Tk()

# ---

# create scrolled frame with vertical and horizontal scrollbar
sf = ScrolledFrame(root, True, True) # 
sf.pack(fill='both', expand=True) # changed

# you  have to use `sf.frame` as parent for widgets
display_players(sf.frame, data)

root.mainloop()
```

Result on Linux

[image]

---

**EDIT:** I changed few lines to correctly resize it when window change size.

Comment: I have a slight issue with this code, when I resize the output window the scrollbars stay in place, they don't move along with the window edges. How can I do that?

Comment: @SohanChopdekar I changed few lines inside ScrolledFrame and one in main part which shows how to use it. See `# changed` in code.